# Why does this file not play as the startup sound?

Tags: sound, login, lightdm

I downloaded a 3.9MB song (.mp3) and converted it to (.ogg) with this command

```
ffmpeg -i desktop-login.mp3 desktop-login.ogg
```

The file size of the converted file was 23.1MB then I copied it to `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo`and i opened it to check if it got copied (replaced with the original) properly, and it was.
But when i start the computer the login sound doesn't play.
now what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check if the file actually plays in vlc, smplayer, banshee or what ever you use. With smplayer it would be...

```
smplayer desktop-login.ogg
```

A 3.9 Mb mp3 converted to ogg should be a little bit smaller than the mp3 if it is the same bitrate so it might not be a sound file.

And I would also expect to see the bitrate in the command. Example:

```
ffmpeg -i desktop-login.mp3 -ab 6400 desktop-login.ogg
```

But the main problem will probably be the size: the original filesize is 100 kB. I would expect your filesize to have to be around that size. You can use audacity to quickly cut a smaller piece and try that!

Also make sure if the owner is root that the permissions need to be 644 (`sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/*`)

Comment: Checked the sound and it works, Permission is root. only thing left is to try with a smaller file. will tell the results after I try.

Comment: I can not find any limit for the file size though :P

Comment: It was the file size, I shortened it with Audacity and then it worked :D

Comment: 512 kB or 1 mB? >:D

Comment: ripped it to 312 kB xD

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the permission for group and other is set to read only, and see if that helps.  Also see if you can reduce the file size.

Comment: It is set to 'read only' for both, about your point about reducing file size, do u know whats the limit?